# Map ObjectId of MongoDB to more Angular friendly version

Tags: angular, mongodb

Currently the backend responds with this

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "timestamp": 1583485841,
            "machineIdentifier": 3421823,
            "processIdentifier": 21256,
            "counter": 6300739,
            "date": "2020-03-06T09:10:41.000+0000",
            "time": 1583485841000,
            "timeSecond": 1583485841
        },
        "task": "my saved value"
    }
]
```

In Angular I get a list of my desired tasks, now I want to edit the tasks. I expect to access the tasks using the id. My domain object is now

```
export class ValueDomainObject {
  public id: any;
  public task: string;

  constructor(data: any) {
    if (data) {
      this.id = data._id;
      this.task= data.task;
     }
  }
}
```

The mapped id is `undefined` , The value of task has the correct value
the tasks are mapped correctly, now I want to update the value using the objectId, how can I map the objectId of the response, to a string that I can sent to my endpoint

The endpoint I should use is `DOMAIN/evaluate/ID-AS-STRING/task`

Comment: isn't the id '_id' instead of 'id'?

Comment: yes I have updated the post

Comment: Is the data of the constructor the json you posted above so yes, it's an array of objects so what has to be done is: `this.id = data[0]._id;`.

Comment: are you sure that this is the data you recieve? It's syntax is correct, and it maps just fine in the console. Are you sure the backend sends the "_id" attribute?